# Rewriting url to use dots to look like domain instead of slashes

Tags: php, apache, yii

If I have  address like

http://www.smth.com/likewebsite

How do I set route or what needed to have access to the same page with:

http://www.likewebsite.smth.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the urlManager of Yii? Do look into it, if you are not.

```
'rules'=>array(
  [...]
  'http://www.<subdomain:\w+>.smth.com' => '<subdomain>',
)
```

Above code is untested but should give you an idea.